# being connected of R^infinity?

Tags: general-topology

is $\mathbb R^\infty$ ($\mathbb R\times \mathbb R\times \mathbb R\times \mathbb R\times\cdots$) connected with  metric $P$?

$P(x,y)=\sup\{D(x(k),y(k))\mid k\in\mathbb N\}$

for all $i$: $D(x(i),y(i))=\min\{d(x(i),y(i)),1\}$

and $d$ is the standard metric on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Could you type this on LATEX, I am not really getting what the metric is...

Comment: @Thorben: It's just the uniform metric capped at $1$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Consider the set of all bounded sequences. Is it open? Is it closed?